# Print statement is exiting for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

My goal is to chunk an array into blocks, and loop over those blocks in a `for`-loop. While looping, I would also like to print the percentage of the data that I have looped over so far (because in practice I'll be making requests on each loop, which will cause the loop to take a long time...)

Here is the code:

```
# Function to chunk the data
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

# Init data and chunks
d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
chunked = chunker(d, 2)

i = 1
for chunk in chunked:
    print(i)
    print(str((i / len(list(chunked)) * 100)) + '%')
    i += 1
    print('end')
```

If you run this code, the loop will only run once.

However, if you comment/delete the `print(str((i / len(list(chunked)) * 100)) + '%')` statement inside the loop, then it will run 5 times, which is the expected behavior.

Why would my `print` statement be causing my loop to exit?

Comment: Your function `chunker` returns a generator rather than a list or a tuple. So when in your print statement you call `list(chunked)` you are pulling the rest of the values out of the generator so by the next iteration through the loop the generator is exhausted and the loop ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chunked` is a generator, not a list, so you can only iterate over it once. When you call `list(chunked)`, it consumes the rest of the generator, so there's nothing left for the `for` loop to iterate over.

Also, `len(list(chunked))` will be 1 less than you expect, since it doesn't include the current element of the iteration in the list.

Change `chunker` to use a list comprehension instead of returning a generator.

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    return [seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `list(chunked)` in your call to `print()` and that exhausts the `chunked` generator. `for chunk in chunked` doesn't get any next items, so it exits.

Answer (score 1):

I also seem to be interested to display a progress bar. If you convert the generator to a list before you iterate over it, you can use a library called `tqdm`. Be sure not to print anything inside the for loop to save your terminal from going brr.

Run this code after `$pip install tqdm`

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

def chunker(seq, size):
    return list(seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

# Init data and chunks
d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
chunked = chunker(d, 2)
print(chunked)
i = 1

for chunk in tqdm(chunked, desc='Iterating on chunked data'):
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
Iterating on chunked data: 100%|██████████████████████████| 5/5 [00:02<00:00,  1.96it/s]
```